# How to compute substraction of the data from different alias in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

```
dump count_a;
(10)

dump count_b;
(20)

dump count_c;
(30)
```

Now I want to to calculate: count_c - count_b - count_a. How to achieve this in PIG script ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join the three aliases together, for which you'll need a common field to join upon. Assuming they are all single record aliases you can create a field n to join on:

```
prep_a = FOREACH count_a GENERATE 1 AS n, a; 
prep_b = FOREACH count_b GENERATE 1 AS n, b; 
prep_c = FOREACH count_c GENERATE 1 AS n, c;
```

Then you can join a & b & c all by the common field n:

```
ab = JOIN prep_a by n FULL, prep_b by n;
abc = JOIN ab by prep_a::n FULL, prep_c by n;
```

Then finally calculate the final result:

```
result = FOREACH abc GENERATE (c - b - a) AS result;
```

Comment: Since you're just doing a regular join and not worrying about keys being present or not, you can do it all in a single statement: `abc = JOIN prep_a BY n, prep_b BY n, prep_c BY n;`